# Wordpress, display more posts on a subpages

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

i want to show more posts on my subpages

**My code in the functions.php**

```
function number_of_posts($query)
{
    if($query->is_main_query())
    {
       $paged = $query->get( 'paged' );
       if ( ! $paged || $paged < 2 ) 
       {

       } 
       else 
       {
           $query->set('posts_per_page', 24);
       }
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'number_of_posts');
```

**Problem:**
On the first page i get a wrong pagination. It shows a link to subpage 4 but a subpage 4 doesn't exit.

I think i must add something like this

```
....
if ( ! $paged || $paged < 2 ) 
{

// show only 10 posts but calculate the pagination with 18 posts

} 
.....
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Well i guess you need to actually modify the code of pagination instead of this one as Pagination will calculate the pages based on the fixed number_of_posts so due to that you are facing this error

Comment: @Anandthakkar pagination work the main query's `$max_num_pages` property which is calculated by dividing the `$found_posts`  by the amount of posts per page. All you need to do is to alter the `$found_posts` property with the `found_posts` filter

Comment: Can you be more specific by what you mean by 'subpages'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a modified version of a post I have done on WPSE a while ago

### FROM [WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/192562/31545)

**STEP 1**

We neet to get the `posts_per_page` option set from the back end (which should be set to 10) and also set your `offset` which we are going to use. That will be `14` as you will need 24 posts on page one and 24 on the rest.

If you don't want to alter the `posts_per_page` option, you can then just simply set the variable `$ppg` to `10`

```
$ppg = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
//$ppg = 10;
$offset = 14;
```

**STEP 2**

On page one, you'll need to subtract the `offset` to `posts_per_page`

```
$query->set( 'posts_per_page', $ppp - $offset );
```

**STEP 3**

You must apply your `offset` to all subsequent pages, otherwise you will get a repetition of the last post of the page on the next page

```
$offset = ( ( $query->query_vars['paged']-1 ) * $ppp ) - $offset;
$query->set( 'posts_per_page', $ppp );
$query->set( 'offset', $offset );
```

**STEP 4**

Lastly, you need to add your offset to `found_posts` otherwise your pagination will will not show the last page

```
add_filter( 'found_posts', function ( $found_posts, $query ) 
{
    $offset = 14;

    if( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $found_posts = $found_posts + $offset;
    }
    return $found_posts;
}, 10, 2 );
```

**ALL TOGETHER**

This is how your complete query will look like that should go into functions.php

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) 
{
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $ppp    = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
        //$ppp  = 10;
        $offset = 14;

        if ( !$query->is_paged() ) {
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $ppp - $offset );
        } else {
            $offset = ( ( $query->query_vars['paged']-1 ) * $ppp ) - $offset;
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $ppp );
            $query->set( 'offset', $offset );
        }
    }
});

add_filter( 'found_posts', function ( $found_posts, $query ) 
{
    $offset = 14;

    if( $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $found_posts = $found_posts + $offset;
    }
    return $found_posts;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php 
function number_of_posts($query)
{
    if($query->is_main_query())
    {
       $paged = $query->get( 'paged' );

       //if page is less than 2 get 10 post on that page (that is on page 1)
       if ( ! $paged || $paged < 2 ) 
       {
            $query->set('posts_per_page', 10);
       } 
       else 
       {
           $query->set('posts_per_page', 24);
       }
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'number_of_posts');?>
```

and in the main query where you have specified all the arguments for Wp_Query . please add `$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;`